# effect of updating data from multiple users sql php

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a question please, 
I am making an online store.
It offers a product with an available quantity attribute
Let's imagine a certain product has 1 quantity available only.
2 users are logged in and added this element to cart.
They both at the same time checked out (I am trying to do this by splitting 2 browsers in the screen and pressing at the checkout button simultaneously.)
How can I manage that the product checkout is successful for only one user in this case?

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if(isset($_POST['qty_array'])&&isset($_POST['ids_array'])){
          $order_address=$_POST['addressCart'];
          $ids_array=$_POST['ids_array']; //this is array of product ids in the cart
          $qty_array=$_POST['qty_array']; // this is array of quantities in the cart
          $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

          $j=0;
          $x=0;
          foreach($ids_array as $id){
            $query = "SELECT available_quantity from products where product_id='$id' AND   product_active=1";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $qty1=$qty_array[$j];
            if($row['available_quantity']==0 || $qty1>$row['available_quantity']){
              $x++;
            }
            $j++;
          }

          if($x!=0){
            $msg="unable_checkout";
               echo $msg;
          }

      else{
        $bool=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO order_table(customer_id,order_date,order_address)
        VALUES ('$customerID','$date','$order_address')") or  die("".mysqli_error($db));
        $order_id=mysqli_insert_id($db);
        if($bool){
              $k=0;
              foreach($ids_array as $id){
                $query2 = "SELECT * from products where product_id='$id' AND product_active=1";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$query2);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                $qty_available=$row2['available_quantity'];
                $qty=$qty_array[$k];
                $unitprice=$row2['product_price'];
                $discount=$row2['product_discount'];
                if($qty<=$qty_available && isset($_SESSION['cartProds']) && $qty_available!=0 ){
                  mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO order_details(order_id,product_id,unitprice,discount,quantity)
                  VALUES ('$order_id','$id','$unitprice','$discount','$qty')") or  die("".mysqli_error($db));
                  $newqty=$qty_available-$qty;
                  mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE products SET available_quantity='$newqty' WHERE product_id='$id'");
                }
                $k++;
                }
              }
              $msg="checkedout_successfully";
              //unset inserted order :
              unset($_SESSION['cartProds']);
              $_SESSION['nOfProds']=0;
              echo $msg;
        }


      }
```

I need to stop the submission and to not insert anything when one of the quantities is equal to Zero.

What I am getting is that if 2 users want to checkout 3 same products at the same time (one product is added to order table of user 1 , and the other 2 are added to order table of user2 ..which is wrong , I want in this case to make checkout successful for only one user, and to give a warning alert msg for the second user)

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#enableAddress").change(function(){
      if($("#enableAddress").prop("checked") == true){
      $("#addressCart").prop('disabled',false);
      }
      else{
        $("#addressCart").prop('disabled',true);
      }
    });


  $("#checkoutBtn").click(function(){


    var ids_array = [];
        $('input[name^=checkoutHidden]').each(function(){
            ids_array.push($(this).val());
        });

    var qty_array = [];
        $('input[name^=quantity]').each(function(){
          qty_array.push($(this).val());
          });

    var telCart =   $("#telCart").val();
    var addressCart = $("#addressCart").val();



                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "../phpOnly/checkOut.php",
                     data: { ids_array:ids_array, qty_array:qty_array,addressCart:addressCart},
                     success: function(msg) {
                       // alert(msg);
                       if(msg=="checkedout_successfully"){
                          // $("#orderMsg").fadeIn(3000);
                          // $("#cartBody").fadeOut(2000);
                          // $("#nOfProdsSpan").text('0');
                          alert(msg);
                        }
                       else if(msg=="unable_checkout"){
                          // window.location.href="#";
                          // $("#inavailableMsg").fadeIn(1000);
                          alert(msg);
                       }
                      }
                });



});




});
```

**Don't forget that I am taking into consideration that the available quantity is only 1 ( which only one user can order it only)**

Answer (score 0):

An approach to handle concurency would be to change the logic, and start the process by attempting to `update` the `products` table, with a `where` clause that ensures that the requested quantity is available, like so:

```
UPDATE products 
SET available_quantity = available_quantity - 1
WHERE 
    product_id = :id
    AND product_active = 1
    AND available_quantity > 0
```

You can then check the number of rows affected by the query:

- if one row was affected, then it means the that check out did succeed; you can then do the rest of the process (create the order and the order details records)
- if no row was affected, then the check out failed; do not create the order

With this technique, you let the database handle the concurrency for you, and you are guaranteed to never sell more product than available.

Comment: Ok @GMB I've got your suggestion.
But, if more than one product is currently in the cart, I will loop around the products, and start updating the products table as you suggested.. What if the first product was affected and updated, but the second product didn't since available quantity is zero.. then there is one product updated and one didn't update...

I don't want this, I want that if only one product isn't available, I need to prevent any update and return a warning msg for the user to re-checkout for available products only...